# How do I efficiently read / write an unsigned 16 bit integer in a JavaScript buffer?

Tags: javascript, binary, buffer

I'm trying to store positive integers between 0 and 65,535, but these functions use signed integer logic, throwing an error :

```
[ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= -32768 and <= 32767. Received 40983
```

Code:

```
const readInt16 = (b) => {
  return b.readUInt16BE(0);
}
const setInt16 = (int16) => {
  // realistically the buffer is allocated outside the func and re-used
  const b = Buffer.alloc(2); 
  b.writeInt16LE(int16)
  return b;
}
```

How can I read/write 16 bit unsigned integers efficiently to a buffer in JavaScript?

I realize I could offset the values by -32768 and then shift them back when reading, but that's an extra math step and read speed performance in my code is absolutely critical. If it's possible to do this without any extra math, that's highly preferable. Native functions for doing these things use optimized C++ code, leading to such good performance that even small math operations make a non-trivial difference if it's just those two instructions in the func.

Comment: Use `b.writeUInt16LE()`.  You're missing the `U`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is that you're trying to do?  It's hard to give an answer about efficiency without seeing the bigger picture.

Comment: @Brad It's literally that simple? I looked through the documentation and didnt notice the two separate versions, jeez. Thanks man. Edit: Apparently I even used the correct version in the reading func..